# Magento2 : Pagination - jump to top of page

Tags: magento2, product-list, pagination

I have problem with next/previous Buttons in Pagination on category listing page.

[image]

If user click's on next/previous button, it reloads the page (I think) in Ajax at the current page scroll position. Is there any method to force the reload jump to top of page?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question does not belong to Magento (in my opinion). Please explain a bit more if you think that your question is valid for this site.

Comment: Because why? If have this problem in Magento2 pagination. Why should it be off-topic? Normal JS solutions doesnt work. I think, thats a M2 problem...

Comment: Could be closed/deleted.
Its a fault from an extension.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using jquery, add the following script in phtml file.

```
<script>
 require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
  $(".class of your nav button").click(function() {
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  });
</script>
```

use your nav button class like  $(".nav_btn")

or

you can use following code in success event of ajax

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

or make a function and call the function on click of the button

```
 <script>

function movetotop(){
     require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){

      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      }
    </script>
```

and call this function like `<a class ="nav_btn" href="#" onclick="movetotop()" ></a>`

write the script outside of the file that is updating on ajax request

Comment: Good answer. +1

Comment: I use this (2 pagination at top and bottom), but it only works for the 1st time
`.require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){
   $("ul.pages-items a").each(function(index) {
  $(this).click(function() {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
  });
 });
});`

Comment: then make a function and write the script in it and call the function on click of the button