# pagination using jquery

Tags: magento2, javascript, ajax, jquery, pagination

I have a search bar on my page when I search for something it returns the result perfectly with correct pagination. As shown below [image: pagination image]

but when I clicked on page 2, it returns the data correctly but instead of showing it in the proper form it just prints the whole HTML page.

The code that I have written inside JSON's successful response is that.

```
success : function(res) {
    $('#replaceIt').html(res);
}
```

instead of showing the 2nd page it just shows this.

[image: result after click on page 2]

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265453/magento2-pagination-jump-to-top-of-page

Comment: check this above link

Comment: thankx for your reply but My problem was different and I have resolved it

Comment: you welcome bro